# How to check if a docker image is configured to run as “root” (Linux) or “Container Administrator” (Windows)

Tags: docker, containers

How to check if a docker image is configured to run as “root” (Linux) or “Container Administrator” (Windows). Need the commands for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to say who is the user used to execute commands inside the docker container if yes you can run this command?

```
docker exec -it CONTAINER_ID /bin/bash
```

then run **whoami** inside the container.